# Next Panorama ID in street view

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I have a develop for to get a panoramic photo with a specif longitude-latitude in Street View. With GoogleMaps API, I can get the route (see image) from ***point A*** to ***point B***. But I need the next pano_id in that route. How can I get that?

[image]
I have this for now. Every black point is a step for the function *DirectionDisplay*, with the next code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < myroute.legs[i].steps.length; j++ ){
                      for (var k = 0; k < myroute.legs[i].steps[j].lat_lngs.length; k++ ){
                        var start = myroute.legs[i].steps[j].lat_lngs[k];
                        var coords = start.lat() + '|' + start.lng() ;
                        console.info('cooords',coords);
                    }
                  }
```

I can get the longitude latitude of two points, but i need the longitude latitude of each 2 or 3 mts, (similar when you press the arrow in google street view). Like [This Example](http://tripgeo.com/DirectionsMapExamples.aspx?id=2)

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmJsc.png)

**EDIT**:

I'm getting the Panorama ID with this code:

```
sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
sv.getPanorama({location: myLatLng, radius: 50}, processSVData);

function processSVData(info, status) {
$.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              url: "{{ url_for('download_tiles') }}",
              async: false,
              data: JSON.stringify({pano_id: info.location.pano}),
              success: function(response){
               }

   .... //get little images of panorama I later I build the panorama.
       //I get the panorama with the ID of the panorama.
}
```

For now, I'm getting the Panorama photo in a specific longitude latitude. `mylatlng` is the variable with the longitude and latitude,
[image]
(I'm drawing the red lines manually)

**EDIT:**

For example: [this](https://www.google.com.co/maps/dir/40.7284265,-73.9942564/40.7278422,-73.9947541/@40.7281321,-73.9950543,19z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0?hl=es) route in *GoogleMaps*. The variable `myroute.legs[i].steps[j].lat_lngs[k]` have 3 longitude - latitude. But in StreetView, I can do 6 clics, from (Brodway,E 4th St) to (Brodway,W 3rd st)

thanks,

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates how you are getting the StreetView.  The StreetViewPanorama allows access to `links` to nearby panoramas

Comment: Hi @geocodezip, thanks for to see my question. I already corrected it. do you have any idea how can I  get the list of position through the route? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Post this answer if someone needs this too.
The wrong it is not a proporty of Googmaps, is a property of StreetView.
StreetView have and object [StreetViewPanorama](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama). With that object is possible get the links (arrow with the next panorama ID). so you need to create a StreetViewPanorama objetc.

```
var panorama = new StreetViewPanorama...;.
panorama.setPano('some panorama id');
var links = panorama.getLinks();
links[0].getPano(); //will be the next panorama y random direction, or the specified in the POV variable.
```